# Get Combine Records from SQL SERVER with Distinct and comma Separated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three Tables.

1. Group
2. Extension
3. Extention_Group (Is a Middle table having GroupID and ExtensionID as reference IDs)

I have three queries which I'm using right now,

Query for getting distinct items from `Extention_Group` Table on the basis of GroupID

```
select distinct GroupID from Extention_Group order by GroupID
```

Query for getting required required columns from tables

```
select g.ID as GroupID, g.Name as GroupName, eg.ExtentionID from [Group] g 
inner join Extention_Group eg on eg.GroupId = g.Id  
inner join UserProfile up on eg.ExtentionID = up.UserProfileID
```

And Query for getting extensions as CSV (Comma Separated Values)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + up.Extension
FROM userprofile up
ORDER BY up.Extension
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CsvExtension
```

[image: Queries executing perfectly]

What I actually want is to combine all of these results into a single table.
How I can combine these three results in to one single table, So that I can use it easily.
I have already tried UNIONS but no success.

Answer (score 0):

It can be combine like this,

```
 select g.ID as GroupID, g.Name as GroupName, up.Extension, eg.ExtentionID
,stuff((SELECT ',' + up.Extension FROM userprofile up1 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CsvExtension
,EG1.Groupid as [distinct Groupid] 
from [Group] g  
inner join Extention_Group eg on eg.GroupId = g.Id  
inner join UserProfile up on eg.ExtentionID = up.UserProfileID
inner join (select distinct GroupID from Extention_Group ) EG1 on eg.groupid=eg1.groupid
```

knowing the exact relation and data can help optimizing it.I don't exactly know how it behave.May be you should remove the where clause from "xml path select"